# How to infer type in this component setup?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have an item object that I collect from this custom hook (from [React DnD](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop)). The problem is that typescript doesn't allow me to access its property in the drop function below, because its type is unknown.

```
function MyComponent(props){

   const [{item}, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: "BLOCK",
        collect: monitor => ({
            item: monitor.getItem() // Item object collected here IDropTargetMonitor
        }),
        drop: (): void => setBlock_name(item.block_name) // /!\ Object [item] is of type 'unknown'
    })

  return ...
}
```

The corresponding interface in the module is the following :

```
export interface DropTargetMonitor<DragObject = unknown, DropResult = unknown>
```

I define what I want in the item object here :

```
const OtherComponent = (props) => {

    const [{isDragging}, drag] = useDrag({
        type: "BLOCK",
        item: {blockName: props.blockName}, // blockName is a string
        collect: monitor => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        })
    })

    return ...
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could give me an hint on how I could infer the item type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that can be adjusted from your code. `useDrop` is a generic that accepts the types for the dragged item. It's defined as:

```
 useDrop<DragObject = unknown, DropResult = unknown, CollectedProps = unknown>
```

You could create an interface for your item:

```
interface Item {
  blockName: string;
}
```

and then refactor your `useDrop` hook like:

```
const [{item}, drop] = useDrop<Item, unknown, {item: Item}>({
    accept: "BLOCK",
    collect: monitor => ({
        item: monitor.getItem() 
    }),
    drop: (item: Item): void => setBlock_name(item.blockName)
})
```

This way Typescript will know that `item` is of type `Item`. A couple things to notice is that in your code you had `setBlock_name(item.block_name)` but it should be `setBlock_name(item.blockName)` since in your `useDrag` you used `item: {blockName: props.blockName}` so the property name is `blockName` instead of `block_name`. The other thing is that if you're gonna use the dropped item in your `drop` method in `useDrop` you should use the one that is passed as the first argument for `drop: (item) => void`, you don't need to capture item in the `collect` function. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I got it ! Thanks a lot. I have been struggling with this one for a certain time now. For the second matter, I cut the code for clarity purposes, and some mistakes slipped through. I'm not going to fix them for people who might read your comment and no longer understand what you've meant.